Bitbucket Pipeline Cache Issue over steps
image: node:20

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: 
          name: Install Dependencies
          caches:
            - node  
          script:
            - npm install  
      - step:
          name: Checking Format
          caches:
            - node  
          script:
            - npm run format-check

      - step:
          name: Run Tests
          caches:
            - node  
          script:
            - npm run test

definitions:
  caches:
    node: node_modules 

the dependencies not being cached or retrieved over next steps. Its bitbucket-pipelines.yml i want to setup pipeline in my project. `
Error: > prettier --check "**/*.{ts,tsx}"
sh: 1: prettier: not found
+ umask 000`.      Fix it


is prettier in your package.json file

Have you confirmed in the build teardown that a cache is created or exists? Can you run that command after npm install step?
